# How To Know If the listbox is empty

Tags: vb.net

sir how can i know if my listbox is empty or not?

i dont really have an idea for that. i'd try this but its wrong 
if listbox1.items = ""
end if

thank you

Comment: The first thing a vb.net developer should learn is to set the strict compiler options to on. Read the section *"To set Option Strict in the IDE"* in this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx

Comment: A down vote? Shouldn't be - maybe a mistake. Simple questions does have their place as well - they help to learn and quickly get up to speed. Moreover those who ask questions learn quicker. +1

Answer (score 5):

There is a property ListBox.Items and you should try if Count is greater than 0
example:

```
If ListBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then
    YOURCODE
END IF
```

You should always use msdn library to check simple things like that. For example link to ListBox documentation is under https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: To be honest, this question should be protected, but also, Microsoft documentation is hard to understand sometimes depending on what level of coding you have accomplished. There was a time where the documentation wasn't useful at all due to me just starting out, now the documentation is easier to read but still sloppy. They really need to do some revamping of the documentation. +1 for the answer.